# Validate XML in java using a schema with nested imports

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xerces

I'm trying to validate an XML string against an xsd schema using nested imports:

`types.xsd`

```xml
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/types" xmlns:gef="http://www.example.com/geofencing">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/implementations" schemaLocation="implementationsV2.1.xsd"/>  
  <xsd:element name="geofencingMode">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="mode" type="gef:modeId"/>
      <xsd:attribute name="period" type="gef:periodId"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</schema>
```

`implementationsV2.1.xsd`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/implementations" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.com/geofencing" schemaLocation="geofencingServiceV2.1.xsd">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>...</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:import>
</schema>
```

`geofencingServiceV2.1.xsd`

```xml
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/geofencing"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.com/geofencing">
    <xsd:simpleType name="modeId">
        ...
    </xsd:simpleType>
</schema>
```

With the following validation code:

```java
private void validateResponseSchema(String response) throws IOException, SAXException {
  SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
  Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new ClassPathResource("types.xsd").getURL());
  Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
  validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes())));
}
```

And I get the error:

```java
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/.../types.xsd; lineNumber: 358; columnNumber: 87; src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'gef:modeId'.
  It was detected that 'gef:modeId' is in namespace 'http://www.example.com/geofencing', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:/.../types.xsd'.
  If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'gef:modeId' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'file:/.../types.xsd'.
```

If I directly import the `geofencing` namespace in the `types.xsd` it works, but I don't understand why it would be necessary.

- I included one namespace here but several are present in `implementations`
- I can't easily modify the xsds I'm validating against
- From debugging I can confirm that the linked files are correctly resolved

Is there an option maybe I'm missing ? This error seems specific to the java library used under the hood (apache xerces) as the schema is valid otherwise.